# iOS) How to set parameter when getting response using AFHTTPRequestOperation with 'GET' method

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

My code is below:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/players?skip=%ld",(long)skipSize] DVURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//[request set]
[request setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[filter filteringDictionary]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"responseObject %@", responseObject);

     totalPages = ([[responseObject
                     objectForKey:@"count"] intValue] / 20);
     NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"players"]);
     for (NSDictionary *playerDict in [responseObject objectForKey:@"players"]) {
         DVPlayer *player = [[DVPlayer alloc] initWithDictionary:playerDict];
         if (![self.playerArray.players containsObject:player]) {
             [self.playerArray.players addObject:player];
         }
     }
     [playerCollectionView reloadData];

 } failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     [[[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Error fetching players!"
        message:@"Please try again later"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
 }];

[operation start];
```

When I use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, I used `NSDictionary` as parameter for GET method.

So I thought `[request setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[filter filteringDictionary]];` would be corresponding.

But I got an error :

> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for name(ex)

I architected the parameter is `NSDictionary` for convenience...
Can't I set parameter as `NSDictionary` when using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` , not `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`?

Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` takes an `NSURLRequest` as an init parameter. As such, you need to handle the serialization yourself, append it to your url, and then encode the url:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[yourUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

Just one more reason why `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is easier ;)